# How to deploy Laravel application on Kubernetes using docker and GitLab?

Tags: laravel, docker, kubernetes, gitlab, laradock

I am having this laravel application which I need to deploy on Kubernetes. I am using laradock in my app to facilitate docker, using gitlab for version controlling and CI/CD operations.
It will be great if someone provide me sort of roadmap to achieve this. Would be great help.

Comment: you can use the gitlab and kubernetes integration already there to deploy to k8s from gitlab

Comment: I am actually looking for steps or specific commands to deploy this using docker created through laradock